# generate file hash in python

Tags: python, hash

hi this code generate sha1 hash but hash differ from other tools generate  sha1 hash from this file:

```
import os
import hashlib

fileList = os.listdir("D:\\a\\")
for i in fileList:
d=(hashlib.sha1(file("D:\\a\\"+i, 'r').read()).hexdigest())
# os.rename(i,d)
print(d)
```

in MD5 so i have this problem!!
why?

---

edit: 'rb'  solve my problem

Comment: not sure sha1 always generate same hash or not but you may try with "rb"

Comment: Maybe because you're using sha1hash in Python and comparing it to a MD5 hash? If this is not it, consider rewriting the question, it's pretty difficult to make sense of it.

Comment: MD5: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5; SHA1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using 'rb' and also try using the md5 method - at present you are using SHA1 - which is a different algorithm, and I presume from your explanation that the other tools are using md5.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import hashlib

fileList = os.walk("c:\\temp")
for tuple in fileList:
    for item in tuple[2]:
        d = hashlib.md5(file(tuple[0] + "\\" + item, 'r').read()).hexdigest()
        print [item, d]
```